# VHDL initialize variable to multiple values

Tags: integer, vhdl

In VHDL is it possible to sequentially assign values to a variable of type INTEGER? For example, I have a behavior file that has a matrix that loads value from a variable called DIN of type INTEGER. In the testbench I would think I need to assign values that DIN can have in which case I would need 8x8 values. How can I do so when my only inputs are DIN, CLK, and START?

Comment: Do you have some code that shows the types and structure of the design or test bench ?  Think that will greatly help understanding the question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that the question can be interpreted as: "given a 2D array of  integers, how can I initialize it one value at a time?"

If this is the case, here's a possible solution:

- you will need two internal signals of integer type to index the array elements (say `current_row` and `current_column`)
- you will need a reset signal to put your registers in a known state upon initialization (`current_row`, `current_column`, and your matrix elements should be set to 0 when reset is asserted)
- on every clock pulse, assign the value from d_in to an element in your matrix: `matrix(current_row, current_column) <= d_in`
- on every clock pulse, update `current_row` and `current_column` so that they cycle through the entire matrix in the correct order

The implementation details are left to the reader, but this should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the sequential values in some kind of array, and then your testbench can step through the array assigning the values in turn to the DIN signal.